# Will V8 Generate Hidden Classes for an Object Used as an Associative Array? (Large number of properties)

Tags: properties, set, associative-array, v8, internals

I am trying to implement a straightforward associative array (no duplicates) with string keys and instances of my own "classes" as values in JavaScript. I am happy with expected O(1) behaviour of a hash set or the O(log n) access time of a set implemented as a balanced tree.

I am drawn to the simple use of an object to which I dynamically add new properties but I am on Node.js and have come across the V8 optimisation of hidden classes ([see description of V8 hidden classes here](http://clipboard.com/clip/LQIbXIAzXp2T1zif8o7AVvNc3QtuvocW5uqe)).

If I do use properties on an object, will the V8 runtime notice the sheer number of properties and their transience and stop trying to JIT hidden classes behind the scenes?

I just cloned the V8 code, so pointers into it would be welcome alongside the top-line answer to my question.

Thanks for your help.

**Follow-up 1**

Thanks @vyacheslav-egorov, I see the guard code below in `JSObject::AddFastProperty` at your link. Without digging through more code it seems like a lot of overhead on every new property insertion. I think I see something like a per-object mode which causes `JSObject::AddFastProperty` to never be called any more. So `JSObject::AddProperty` calls straight through to `JSObject::AddSlowProperty` without much fuss. Do I need to do anything to push an object into that mode, or will the V8 runtime switch it over reliably using its own metrics?

```
if ((!name->IsSymbol() && !IsIdentifier(isolate->unicode_cache(), name)
     && name != isolate->heap()->hidden_string()) ||
    (map()->unused_property_fields() == 0 &&
     TooManyFastProperties(properties()->length(), store_mode))) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, V8 switches object properties to a dictionary representation when it notices that object [has too many properties](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/objects.cc?r=14358#1759).

How many is "too many" depends on several factors (how was the object created, how many properties it had initially, how are properties added to the object). For example if an object was created as an empty object literal "too many" would be around 30 properties.

Comment: Thank you Vyacheslav, any thoughts on my follow-up question?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/16124556/506073 I assume the earlier early-out in ``JSObject::AddProperty`` is enabled automatically along the lines you mention when linking to the deeper test in the call graph ... safe assumption. Sorry, just being a bit pedantic ... been looking at this "simple" issue far too long. Thanks for any input at all! :-)

Comment: Sorry, think my answer is in ``NormalizeProperties`` ... if so, no need to answer.

Comment: once object is pushed into this mode by too many properties it will stay in this mode (well, strictly speaking there is one heuristic to escape back to fast mode: assigning slow object to a `prototype` property of some function will convert it to fast mode). If you want to go to the slow mode early (slow mode is called "slow" for a reason!) you can for example add a property with non-identifier name to the object or to add a property and then `delete` it.

Comment: also if you are implementing some language on top of JavaScript (you say you will have your own "classes") it makes more sense to piggy back on the optimizations existing in the underlying engine than to fight them. Hidden classes exist for a reason.